# Not sure where the float object error is occuring

Tags: python, scipy

I am having trouble with using odeint. I have a problem with my code throwing a TypeError float is not subscriptable when I run it and I am not sure why. It seems like my r0 or my dr list inside the F function is causing the error, but I just don't see what the problem is.

```
    #Import packages to name space
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ode

#Define constants and initial conditions
Cd = 0.35
p_air = 1.2 #kg/m^3
a = 0.037 #m
m = 0.145#kg
g = 9.8 #kgm/s^2
theta = np.pi/4
v0 = 60#m/s
r0 = [0,v0*np.cos(theta),0,v0*np.sin(theta)] #[x0,vx0,y0,vy0]
start,stop,step = 0,10,0.1
t = np.arange(start,stop+step,step)


#Define function to pass into odeint
def F(t,r0,const):
    C,p,a,m,g = const
    dr = [0,0,0,0] #[x',vx',y',vy']
    dr[0] = r0[2]
    dr[2] = r0[3]
    dr[1] = -(1/(2*m))*C*p*np.pi*a**2*r0[1]*np.sqrt(r0[1]**2 + r0[3]**2)
    dr[3] = -(1/(2*m))*C*p*np.pi*a**2*r0[3]*np.sqrt(r0[1]**2 + r0[3]**2) - g
    return dr

result = ode(F,r0,t,args=([Cd,p_air,a,m,g],))
```

The error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-c5fa1231ea3d> in <module>
     26     return dr
     27 
---> 28 result = ode(F,r0,t,args=([Cd,p_air,a,m,g],))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg, tfirst)
    239     t = copy(t)
    240     y0 = copy(y0)
--> 241     output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
    242                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
    243                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords,

<ipython-input-48-c5fa1231ea3d> in F(t, r0, const)
     20     C,p,a,m,g = const
     21     dr = [0,0,0,0] #[x',vx',y',vy']
---> 22     dr[0] = r0[2]
     23     dr[2] = r0[3]
     24     dr[1] = -(1/(2*m))*C*p*np.pi*a**2*r0[1]*np.sqrt(r0[1]**2 + r0[3]**2)

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: It's hard to even find this `r0` what to say about analyzing. Apply some code formatting, now it look like ascii hex dump.

Comment: I'm voting to close because you did not provide a full runnable example.  And after fudging my way around your omissions, I found that you did not define the `F` function as specified by `odeint`

Comment: I didn't include a full runnable version of code because last time I did that people told me not to.

Comment: The point of asking questions on stackoverflow is to provide enough code that the error can be reproduced but omit all irrelevant stuff. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The edited version is much clearer now.

Comment: Before this was closed I made an edit to address the concerns people had with the post. However, it was still closed.

Also, the answer is that the position and time arguments in the F function were in the wrong order.

Comment: @rmiller415, either `dr` or `r0` is a float instead of being iterable. Print it before the line to find out which one is and update the function signature or interface to make it iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the odeint call has this syntax:

```
result = ode(F,r0,t,args=([Cd,p_air,a,m,g],))
```

odeint is expecting to receive function, initial conditions, and time space in that order. But, the function was taking in the time space and initial conditions in the wrong order, by changing the definition line of the function from `def F(t,r0,const):` to `def F(r0,t,const):` it worked fine.